# How to get most recent row in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, select

On my front page I would like my most recent Blog post or message to be displayed.

My current query however displays the messages in order of row number so the oldest or first blog message is displayed and the newest is at the bottom of the page.

I would like it so the most recent 5 blogs are displayed.

In my table "blog" I have columns:

> -blog_id
>
> -title
>
> -author
>
> -date (y-m-d)
>
> -content

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM blog LIMIT 5
```

I tried using SELECT MAX but it only returns one row.

How can I get the last 5 rows etc.

I would like to order it by row_id (blog_id) as some posts may have the same date.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sorting-rows.html

```
SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY date DESC,blog_id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5

Comment: Won't work reliably because the date column does not contain the time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your blog IDs are serial, this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Note that you can't sort by date because it doesn't include the time - if two blogs were created on the same day you don't know which was created later from the date.

Comment: When working with transactions, the largest ID might not be the latest entry.

Comment: Right, but this is as accurate as he's going to get without a creation time column.

Comment: you're probably right that with the current data this is about the best the OP can do (and most of the time it will be right).

Comment: @Wrikken I think this behavior was only in older versions of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `blog` ORDER BY `blog_id` DESC LIMIT 5
```

This will select latest 5 blog posts, beginning with the newest one.